# Should a colon be used in this case?

Tags: grammar

> X was interested in one of the most
>   important challenges: the lack of
>   reliability in bananas' drawings.

I think I read somewhere that, although possible, a colon should be avoided in these situations (in an academic context).

How could I rewrite this?

Comment: I wouldn't say an appropriate use of a colon would be something to be avoided in an academic context.  (I use them in formal academic papers anyway.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colon usage in English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14717/).

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I'm talking about the usage of colon in this specific context

Comment: @RedDwight: Should a colon be used in this case?

Comment: This is an appropriate use of a colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some style books advise against using a colon between two phrases that are not each an independent sentence. The same applies to semicolons. The exception is when what follows begins on a new line or is a true enumeration: then the part before the colon should still be an independent sentence, but what follows is free. That is why some recommend that your colon should be replaced with a comma: *the lack of reliability in bananas' drawings* is not an independent sentence, but rather an apposition, which could easily be attached by a comma.

I agree that it is somewhat more elegant to stick to this rule in ordinary circumstances. However, I don't think there is consensus about this, and you may very well find style guides that disagree; at any rate, the practice of joining non-independent sentences by a colon will most probably be acceptable to the majority of readers.

Answer (score 2):

> X was interested in one of the most important challenges***, namely,*** the lack of reliability in bananas' drawings

You could also use any of these in place of *namely*: that is, that is to say, to be specific, specifically.

Comment: or the latin `i.e.`

Comment: With "namely", and the other words, the "lack of reliability" seems to just be one of the important challenges. That's not it. The colon conveys what I want to say better. Do you think a colon shouldn't be used?

Comment: @John Assymptoth: actually no, "namely" is very specific about this being the only challenge we are talking about.  While there are a number of important challenges (implied by "one of the"), only the lack of reliability is concerning X right now.

Comment: @John: Rhodri is right. Logically you might say that the "namely ..." apposition should specify "the most important challenges" as our first reading; but conversational implication (aka. context) makes sure that in fact we interpret it as specifying "one of the most important challenges" as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is very much the right place to use a colon.  However, if you weren't comfortable with it, a dash would work well.  The dash seems to be becoming a fairly generic use everywhere punctuation mark.