# Use of colon before reasons

Tags: punctuation, colons, sentence-ends

If we say something has advantages over something else, should we write ":" before the reasons or not?

For example,

> A has advantages over B: The value of A is more than B and…

or

> A has advantages over B. The value of A is more than B and…

Comment: Very related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14717/6006

Answer (score 1):

In this case either one works because your list is also a full sentence. And since it's a full sentence, you should begin it with a capital letter.

More info here: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/colon.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you use a colon to introduce a (non-bulleted) list in which each item is an independent clause (i.e., capable of standing on its own as a complete sentence), you should separate each item from the next with a mere semicolon, or even just a comma if all of them are short and simple. For the very next appearance of a period or full stop will signal your reader that whatever your colon introduced has come to its end. The alternative is to follow your colon with an inset and bulleted list; in that case, it is the end of the inset matter (the restoration of normal margins) that marks the end of whatever your colon introduced. Bulleted independent clauses can also be separated each from the next by semicolons or commas, but in this case a period or full stop is also an option.